# Скрипт для компиляции и запуска java файлов в Ubuntu 16.04 desktop

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

**Ubuntu 16.04 desktop** / **Oracle Java 8**

Задача: нужно создать скрипт, который вначале компилирует исходник, например file.java в file.class для последующего запуcка непосредственно программой java. Все это безобразие происходит в **gnome-terminal**. Файлы *.java* и *.class* могут лежать в одном каталоге с скриптом, хотя я конечно хотел бы раскидать их по папкам *source* и *classes*. Запуск скрипта происходит с GUI. Например, вот какой .bat файл был у меня в Windows:

```
cd source
javac -d ../classes Solution.java
cd ../classes
java Solution
pause
```

Берем *Solution.java* из папки *source*, компилим, и результат кладем в *classes*. Потом запускаем скомпилированный файл. Если в результате компиляции возникают ошибки, консоль Windows отображала эти ошибки в консоль, но потом все же запускала *Solution.class*, если он конечно есть в директории. Главное, что все это происходило последовательно - сначала компиляция, потом запуск. Все это нужно для того, чтобы каждый раз не прописывать в консоль полный путь к файлам для компиляции и запуска (к тому же, путь бывает длинный). Потратив несколько клавиатур об голову, рабочий вариант вышел такой:

1) создаю файл, например run.sh

2) В св-вах ставим галку, что он исполняемый

3) в настройках наутилуса выставляем "запускать исполняемые файлы"

4) открываем текстовым редактором файл, и пишем в нем:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'javac Hello.java && java Hello && read L'
```

В итоге получаем почти идеальную картину. Все произойдет последовательно: Запускается компилятор(javac), выполняет свои шаманские дела с *Hello.java*, и **если все хорошо**, выплевывает *Hello.class* в эту же директорию, где потом программа java запускает *Hello.class* на выполнение. Однако, если в коде есть ошибки, компилятор не сработает а консоль просто закроется даже не сообщив о типе ошибки, которая случилась. Вот в этом и проблема.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'cd source && 
javac -d ../classes Hello.java && 
cd .. && 
cd classes && 
java Hello;read'
```

Скрипт должен находиться в корне, вместе с папками *source* и *classes*. В папке *source* должен лежать исходник (в моем случае Hello.java). Скомпилированная версия (Hello.class) кладется в classes и запускается.

*alexander barakin, DimXenon - благодарю*

Comment: [оффтоп]Попробуйте [Groovy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-pg02179/)[/оффтоп]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> просто закроется даже не сообщив о типе ошибки

замените, например, последний оператор `&&` на разделитель `;`.

чтобы запускаемая команда выглядела как:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'javac Hello.java && java Hello; read'
```

тогда команда оболочки `read` запустится независимо от результата выполнения предыдущих команд (и остановит выполнение в ожидании нажатия клавиши <kbd>enter</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

Перенаправьте вывод ошибок в log-файл.

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'javac Hello.java && java Hello && read L' 2> logfile.log
```